# MySQL: loss of precision when casting to decimal from dobule

Tags: mysql, sql, double, decimal, rounding

I have a table in MySQL with two `double` columns.
When I execute the query:

```
select 
    col_1,
    col_2
from user.table1
```

I get the following results:

```
col_1                   col_2
28323.690288713915000   3.877725752582878
```

However, when I try casting the columns into decimal:

```
select 
    cast(col_1 as decimal(30,15)) as col_1,
    cast(col_2 as decimal(30,15)) as col_2
from user.table1
```

MySQL returns the following:

```
col_1                   col_2
28323.690288713920000   3.877725752582878
```

As you can see, the left col_1 gets slightly rounded at the end while col_2 stays the same. I also tried the `CONVERT()` function, but it gave me the same result.

Because of the requirements of the project I'm working on I need to convert `double` columns into `decimal` without the loss of precision.

Why is it happening and is there any way I can prevent this rounding?

MySQL version: 5.1.72-community.

Comment: [The FLOAT and DOUBLE types represent approximate numeric data values.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) Emphasis on approximate.

Comment: Exact numeric vs. approximate numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `double` is guaranteed to store up to 15 decimal significant figures of precision without loss. For some values it will do better than that.

It is an intentionally sparse data type, very effectively designed for scientific computations: it has a huge range given its memory footprint.

If you can arrange your queries to be only sensitive to 15 significant figures, then you'll be fine. Else you'll have no choice but to change the type to a `decimal` in `user.table1`.